# Unique Permutations - with exceptions

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I just did a quiz and it had a question that I brute forced... but I'm certain there is a "mathmatical" formula that "solves" it.

**Permutations of a String**

Say you have a string "abcdef"... count all unique permutations of the string. For a string with all unique options, this is simple: Length Factoral. So 6! = 720 unique combinations.

**Unique Permutations**

Now, when you add duplicates... you take the factoral, and devide by the product of the unique letters: "aaabbb" => 6! / (3! * 3!) => 720 / 36 => 20 unique combinations.

**Unique Permutations, with exclusions**

The part that stumps me:

You have a string, possibly with duplicate data... except now, exclude permutations that start with a space (or a dot, for visibility):

```
"aa.bb" => "aabb." is a valid permutation... ".aabb" is not. 
"aa.bb.cc" => "aa..bbcc" valid permutation. ".aabbcc." not valid. "..aabbcc" is not valid
"a.." => has one valid permutation: "a.."... the others are all duplicates or start with spaces.
```

**My Solution**

My solution - brute force - was to create the permutations... and manually exclude those starting with spaces... O(N!) if I remember correctly.

I know it has something to do with factorals and the number of spaces. But the final answer eludes me.

I should be able to take the length, divide by the counts... and the calculate the distinct number that start with spaces and subtract that.

Comment: just subtract how many permutations there are when the first character is fixed as '.' (which you can figure out using your same logic, by looking at how many permutations the string has with one dot removed)

Answer (score 1):

You partition the first character as a separate case: there are fewer choices for that character.  This changes the first factor of the numerator of the calculation.  For instance, `aa.bb.cc` has only 6 choices for the first character, not 8.  Therefore, the calculation that was

```
8! / (2! 2! 2! 2!)   -- four duplicates
```

is now

```
(6 * 7!) / (2! 2! 2! 2!)   -- we still have four duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you have 5 unique letters,

so you'll have 5! combinations.

Now when you have 5 unique alphabets and one ., then

In the first position, you'll put one of those 5 alphabets. Then, you'll put the rest of them (4 alphabets and 1 .) in 5! ways,

The result being 5*5!

So, the answer according to me should be along the lines of

Let's say you have x unique alphabets, y alphabets in all and z spaces

So the answer should be

y * (y+z-1)! / (`diving for repeated alphabets and spaces combinations`)

Comment: `Let's say x unique, y chars and z spaces. .... y * (y+z-1)! / (...)` - I'm assuming something is off... there is no X in that equation... and I don't think it works out as posted.

Comment: You do not need X in the equation @WernerCD, quoting your example from the question, ` **Unique Permuatations** Now, when you add duplicates... you take the factoral, and devide by the product of the unique letters: "aaabbb" => 6! / (3! * 3!) => 720 / 36 => 20 unique combinations.`