# Generate unique permutations with exceptions/conditions

Tags: r, algorithm, matlab, permutation, combinatorics

I'm having a "computational problem" that I need to simplify. Similar topics seem to be discussed (e.g. this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471604/unique-permutations-with-exceptions)), but I'm having problems finding a good example/solution/algorithm.

What I want is to generate an algorithm that finds unique permutations of the elements in a vector and that does not generate permutations if a certain condition is met, thus certainly decreasing the number of permutations and computations needed.

**Let's start with a simple example without condition/exception:**

It's no problem finding algorithms that can generate unique permutations (see e.g. [John D'Errico's](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/164470) MATLAB code). Assume we have the following binary vector:

```
 x = [1,1,0,0]
```

There are six unique permutations of the vector, including the vector itself:

```
y1 = [1,1,0,0]
y2 = [1,0,1,0]
y3 = [1,0,0,1]
y4 = [0,1,1,0]
y5 = [0,1,0,1]
y6 = [0,0,1,1]
```

**Based on condition:**

What I actually want is to filter all permutations that meet a certain condition:
Example of two conditions:

- don't generate the permutations where the values are 1 and 0 in column 3 and 4 respectively.
- don't generate the permutations where the values are 1 and 1 in column 1 and 2 respectively.

In this case, the only generated permutations should be:

```
y3 = [1,0,0,1]
y5 = [0,1,0,1]
y6 = [0,0,1,1]
```

It is fairly easy to generate all permutations and than just filter all rows where the conditions are not met; however, I can't figure out how to generate an algorithm that from the beginning does exclude permutations of the conditions...

Comment: Why don't you want to generate the permutations and then filter them?

Comment: @mikkola because of the growing length of my vector x - at some point it will generate an immense number of combinations, where multiple are of no use.

Comment: This answer by [Roger Stafford](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/76363-changing-position-of-numbers-in-a-vector) shows a very efficient way to get all possible permutations. Even for `lengths > 10`. Perhaps this helps as an intermediate step to filter them afterwards. Additionally you coud save it as `unit8` to save memory.  `n = size(x,2);
 k = sum(x==1);
 C = nchoosek(1:n,k);
 m = size(C,1); 
 B = zeros(m,n);
 B(repmat((1-m:0)',1,k)+m*C) = 1`

Comment: @Irreducible thanks! It's definitely a start :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `r` tag in the question, here are some base R implementations.

---

- Using recursion, where the criteria checker is devised in `checker`

```
f <- function(L, n) {
  p <- seq_len(L)
  init <- rep(0, L)
  # checker function
  checker <- function(v) {
    !(all(v[1:2] == c(1, 1)) || all(v[3:4] == c(1, 0)))
  }

  # helper function for permuation of positions
  helper <- function(n) {
    if (n == 1) {
      return(as.list(p))
    }
    lst <- Recall(n - 1)
    unlist(
      lapply(lst, \(x) {
        u <- p[p > x[length(x)]]
        if (length(u)) {
          Filter(\(k) checker(replace(init, k, 1)), Map(c, x, u))
        }
      }),
      recursive = FALSE
    )
  }

  lapply(helper(n), replace, x = init, value = 1)
}
```

- Non-recursion version but with `combn` for all possible combinations, which is more concise and understandable:

```
f <- function(L, n) {
  init <- rep(0, L)
  # checker function
  checker <- function(v) {
    !(all(v[1:2] == c(1, 1)) || all(v[3:4] == c(1, 0)))
  }
  Filter(
    length,
    combn(L, 2, \(k) {
      v <- replace(init, k, 1)
      if (checker(v)) v
    }, simplify = FALSE)
  )
}
```

---

## Output

```
> L <- 4

> n <- 2

> f(L, n)
[[1]]
[1] 1 0 0 1

[[2]]
[1] 0 1 0 1

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 1 1
```